# Heaplib.js for firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, heap-memory

I wanted to know if javascript heapLib.js library is available for firefox also. In all the readings i have come across, the library is used with IE specific methods. Also, when i write the following code in firefox, and then debug the code using firebug, it gives me error precisely on the place where ie specific code has been used.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="heapLib.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var heap= new heapLib.ie();    <--- error at this line 
heap.gc();
heap.debugHeap(true);
heap.alloc(512);
heap.alloc("BBBBB","foo");
heap.free("foo");
heap.debugHeap(false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, i am using iceweasel on Debian, though this shouldn't make much of a difference, but i thought ill add this information.

Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou.